# what's the best way to make responsive sites?

Tags: responsive-design

I know HTML and CSS really well but responsive and continually messing around with css media queries is just a pain in the butt. What do you recommend to make my workflow of making my sites responsive less cumbersome? What can I learn to make my job easier?

I see some sites out there where the responsiveness is so dynamic and perfect. CSS media queries don't seem to create this fluidity.

Answer (score 0):

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ 
Bootstrap is compatible with the latest versions of all major browsers. It gracefully degrades when used on older browsers such as Internet Explorer 8.

Since version 2.0 it also supports responsive web design. This means the layout of web pages adjusts dynamically, taking into account the characteristics of the device used (desktop, tablet, mobile phone).

Starting with version 3.0, Bootstrap adopted a mobile first design philosophy, emphasizing responsive design by default.

Bootstrap is open source and available on GitHub. Developers are encouraged to participate in the project and make their own contributions to the platform.

Recently, community members have translated Bootstrap's documentation into various languages, including Chinese, Spanish and Russian.[6]